# How to resolve ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, dbvisualizer

> I have a table `temp` and Im trying to query as below :

```
    SELECT
    LISTAGG( 'MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = '''||CATEGORY||''' THEN "'||"LEVEL"||'" END) AS "'||
    "LEVEL"||'_'||CATEGORY||'"' , ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY CATEGORY, "LEVEL" DESC
    ) AS col2
        FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            "LEVEL",
            CATEGORY
        FROM
            TEMP );
```

`

I get error as [Code: 1489, SQL State: 72000]  ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
Im unable to get rid of this error.
*I'm using SQL Commander of DBVisualizer .*
I also tried to declare variable before but it does not seem to work:

`@ECHO ${col2 ||32767||varchar2}$`

I tried to  `ALTER SYSTEM SET MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED;` which is also giving error : [Code: 2065, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-02065: illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM.

Is there anything wrong in the code front if not what could be the workaround for this

Comment: I believe you indicated in a previous question that you don't expect to have more than 12 columns which, if I understand, means that you don't expect to have more than 4 distinct `category` values.  If that is the case, it doesn't make sense that the `listagg` result would exceed 4000 characters.  Do you have some reason to believe that the result should exceed 4000 characters?  What does `select distinct category from temp` return?

Comment: hi check this for the output :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70bf221ab6eae07d26e8fec7d335b320. Im unable to run using dbvisualizer due to this ERROR : ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
ORA-06512: at line 15

Comment: Max `Sets` I would have in a `temp` table would be 15.

Comment: I'm confused.  If I uncomment the `open v_recordset for v_sql` line (as well as the declaration of `v_recordset`), I'm not getting an error in dbfiddle.  Can you reproduce the error you're seeing in dbfiddle?

Comment: Error is only when you add more more columns .

Comment: This is the ERROR : ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long ORA-06512

Comment: DBFIDDLE doesnt show an error as such but does not give output more than 6 columns. Check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ecb758e82150064695d1f122cfb910e7 while I want all the 12 columns .

Comment: It does if you copy the query that is built in the prior step and run that as the last step https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1cdfc3bf626e18c5d3c3edfd6a4a5d7

Comment: Which one are you suggestin to run first, I didnt get you on this

Comment: I provided a link to a dbfiddle where I made the change in my prior comment.  You'd need to take the SQL statement that is built up and printed out and then run that statement as the last step.

Comment: OK. When I run `v_sql`  directly it runs without giving an error, but on dbviz 10 im getting the above said error. I want it to work on my local dbviz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222446/discussion-between-scope-and-justin-cave).

Comment: ```http://www.br8dba.com/tag/alter-system-set-max_string_sizeextended-scopespfile/``` try these instructions for extending varchar2 size.

Answer (score 1):

If `LISTAGG` won't work (as, obviously, resulting string is longer than 4000 characters), switch to not-that-elegant `XMLAGG` which doesn't have that restriction. Result should be the same (compare these two):

```
SQL> select listagg(dname, ',') within group (order by dname) result
  2  from dept;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING,OPERATIONS,RESEARCH,SALES


SQL> select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, dname ||',') order by dname).extract
  2           ('//text()'), ',') result
  3  from dept;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING,OPERATIONS,RESEARCH,SALES

SQL>
```

Comment: Could you show me for the code I mentioned. I have seen this example all over and tried it many times

Comment: I might try, if you posted test case.

Comment: I have added the link in the comments.